# CSS table border styling

Tags: css, html-table, styling

I have a table where I'd like the row/table head to be red, but with a slightly rounded corner to be smoother than a straight edge, but I also need to space the width between the heading or the radius would be pointless. Only option I can think of is creating an empty th for a divider. But would prefer a CSS fix.

**Code**

```
.restaurant {
width: 80%;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
color: #000000;
border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
z-index: -1;
}
.restaurant tr {
width: 100%;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
border-spacing: 5px;
z-index: -1;
}
.restaurant td {
height: 100%;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
color: #000000;
border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
z-index: -1;
}
.restaurant th {
line-height: 15px;
background-color: #DE0000;
color: #FFFFFF;
border: 5px solid #FFFFFF
border-spacing: 10px;
border-radius: 4px;
}
```

html

```
<table class="restaurant">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">

        <table class="restaurant-corners">
          <tr>
            <td width="10%">
              <img src="/css/images/menu-corner-top-left.png" class="corners">
            </td>
            <td width="80%">
            </td>
            <td width="10%">
              <img src="/css/images/menu-corner-top-right.png" class="corners" align="right">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>

       </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td colspan="2">

        <table class="restaurant-logo" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
              <center><img src="/css/uncletoms.png"></center>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th width="80%">
              <h2>Breakfast</h2>
            </th>
            <th width="20%">
              <h2>Drinks</h2>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </table>
```

Probably more information there then needed. But I wanted to make sure I didn't missing anything.

Comment: Provide code what you have tried instead of hoping for complete your task by just asking?

Comment: Can you create a more complete piece of html that demonstrates the issue? I'm not sure how to interpret "I also need to space the width between the heading or the radius would be pointless". I made [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/1qhch1fj/), but I can't make out what the problem is.

Comment: The issue is the cellspacing is not working. The border radius works, but the spacing between the cells isnt

Comment: @ChrisCox It's because you have `cellspacing="0"`.

Comment: @MrLister Where do you see `cellspacing="0"`?

Comment: [Right here in the html in your question](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0QNGn.png).

Comment: Thanks! I must be ready for bed!

Comment: I would move all the styling into the CSS (widths) and realize that cell spacing in CSS is accomplished via padding on `td` and`th` elements.

Comment: @MrLister that worked. ty!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When designing a table with rounded corners, do not use `border-collapse: collapse`. OP's request for row to be red is vague...Red borders? Text? Background?...Need specifics. We will apply `border-radius` to the table's border and to the first and last `<th>` borders. See the comments in the **Snippet**:

```css
section {
  padding: 20px 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-bottom: 3px ridge #FF6;
  margin: 0 5px 20px;
}
table.x {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 9px 1px #ccc;
  /* This will round the outside border on all 4 corners */
  /* If you want only the head to have rounded corners uncomment *1* ruleset and remove or comment *2*/
  /* border-top-left-radius: 6px; 
     border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  */
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 550px;
}
.x th {
  color: #FFF;
  background: #2C7EDB;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.x tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #FFF;
}
.x tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #D3E9FF;
  color: #333;
}
.x td {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #264D73;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
}
/* Next 2 rulesets are used to create rounded corners to the inner borders of the head */

/* Remove or comment the last 2 rulesets if you don't want the bottom corners rounded */

.x thead th:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
}
.x thead th:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
}
.x tbody tr:last-child td:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
}
.x tbody tr:last-child td:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <table class="x">
    <caption>table.x</caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Col1</th>
        <th>Col2</th>
        <th>Col3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
        <td>Content</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</section>
```